# Jquery Post function return value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, function, post

My first question so here it goes.

My goal is to have a simple form post and if everything checks out proceed.

```
$.post("anotherpage.php", $("#form").serialize(),function(data){

if(data == 'sent'){
alert("True:  " + data);
}    else{
alert("False:  " + data);
}

$("#somediv").text(data);

     });
```

here is 'anotherpage.php'

```
<?php

echo 'sent'; 

?>
```

Here is my problem, '#somediv' shows the word 'sent' but my function fails every time. Also when it does fail when it alerts it looks like this. "False: s..." It makes me think I have some problem up the stream that is effecting this but I don't know what.

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` with Firebug or Chrome to see what's *actually* in `data`.

Comment: Is  "False: s..." literally what you are seeing?

Comment: You should also ensure that you don't have any whitespace after the word "sent" coming from the server. Try `console.log(data.length)` and check that it prints "4"

Comment: It is what i am seeing but i believe the entire word is there but it only shows "s...". if i change it to "1234" in return i see "1...".

Comment: just tried `console.log(data)` and `console.log(data.length)`
results: sent and 6??? This is the echo string copied. `echo 'sent';`

Comment: Seems like you have some whitespace surrounding your data. Make sure the PHP opening tag is the first character on the first line. Also, you can remove the closing PHP tag - it's not necessary, and likely creates the extra whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to be explicit with your HTTP response, it's easy to accidentally return extra whitespace, especially at the end of your PHP block (carriage returns after the closing angle-bracket being the usual suspects).

Some tips:

1. Make sure there is no whitespace before the start of your php block.
2. Explicitly end the response with `exit()` on the last code line of your php block:

e.g.

```
  <?php

  echo 'sent';
  exit(); 

  ?>
```

There are a few cool functions in PHP regarding output control. You can buffer the output, clear it, store it or flush it. [See here for more information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

Comment: Also, if you leave the closing `?>` tag off then you don't ever have to worry about invisible whitespace after it.

Comment: True, but it sends a shiver down my pedantic spine ;) My code soul requires closure!

Comment: The [Zend coding standard](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html) states that, when a file contains only PHP, you _should_ leave the closing tag off. I think it is a cleaner solution than `exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

here is 'anotherpage.php'

```
<?php

echo "var status='sent';"; 

?>



 $.post("anotherpage.php", $("#form").serialize(),function(data){
alert(date);    
eval(date); // its make as perfect js var string;
    alert(date);
if(status == 'sent'){
    alert("True:  " + status );
    }    else{
    alert("False:  " + status );
    }

    $("#somediv").text(status );

         });
```

Comment: Make sure that u access path is correct??? e.i anotherpage.php or http:\domain\anotherpage.php

Comment: First of all: eval is evil. It's better to return JSON, and use jQuery to parse it.